# jquery .data() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with rewriting jquery for pure JavaScript

```
parent.$("#data-store").data('text')
```

How can I express the same in JS?

Comment: it should be `$("#data-store").data('text')`

Comment: Well, for one, your jQuery is incorrect anyways. I'm confused as to what you're attempting to do. The jQuery function as a query selector cannot be returned as a method to an object, so `parent.$()` doesn't work. `$("#data-store").parent().data('text')` would work though.

Comment: I am using iframe, and I am setting the data in parent

Comment: You still can't use `parent.$()` because `$` is a custom selector by jQuery, it's not the equivalent to a `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`

Comment: @Jacedc: It's entirely possible that `parent.$` is correct. Example: `var parent = {}; parent.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);` Done. Now `$` has no jQuery-related meaning, neither does `jQuery`, and `parent.$` is the jQuery function. In the OP's case, I would venture a guess that `parent` is a parent window which has jQuery loaded into it whereas the current window does not.

Comment: it doesn't look to be working: [console](http://i.imgur.com/AI8szDV)

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Supposing your jQuery code is

```
$("#data-store").data('text')
```

Then you can write it without jQuery as

```
document.getElementById('data-store').dataset['text']
```

or to be compatible with old versions of IE :

```
document.getElementById('data-store').getAttribute('data-text')
```

**2)** If you're accessing the elements of the parent window from an iframe, and supposing you don't encounter any cross domain problem (i.e. your pages are served from the same origin), then you can do

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('data-store').getAttribute('data-text')
```

Comment: I believe (possibly) she wants the parent of `#data-store`, which would explain the `parent.$`

Comment: @lipenco Can you build a fiddle ? Are your pages served from the same origin ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you did not set the data by jQuery:

```
parent.document.getElementById('data-store').getAttribute('data-text');
```

If you set the data by jQuery, it is stored in internal jQuery cache and not as an attribute, and you won't be able to get it without reading the jQuery cache object. If you are interested in reading the internal javascript object, it is named jQuery.cache.

Comment: Is the parent window under the same domain name as the iframe?

Comment: yes it is the same, and it is working with parent.$("#data-store").data('text'), but I don't want to include jquery

Comment: Then the only possible explanation is that the data was original set using jQuery. As I mentioned jQuery does not actually set the attribute or store it as a dataset - it instead stores data in a cache object. You can confirm this by inspecting the element and if the 'data-text' attribute is present, and check jQuery.cache and see if the data value is there.